# What happens to completeness when decision and proof procedures are the same

Tags: logic

Suppose one has a logic that is semi-decidable: there exists a decision algorithm - a finite procedure - for showing that a formula is valid whenever it is valid. This could be, for example, a way of recursively enumerating the validities with the guarantee that any valid formula will eventually appear on the list.

Now suppose that we were to take this decision procedure as a semantic *proof* procedure for the logic, i.e., a way of demonstrating, in finitely many steps, the logical truth of the formula. The ``proof'' procedure is to begin listing formulas according to the r.e. of the decision procedure, and the formula is proven when it appears on the list.

**Question:** In this situation where proof and decision procedures are the same, am I right to understand that completeness (of the procedure) and semi-decidability are indistinguishable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If we know (being a bit informal here for simplicity) that the validity problem for a logic is semidecidable, then we also know that *there exists* an effective proof procedure for that logic which is sound and complete, and that that proof procedure basically is the same thing as a semidecision procedure for the validity problem. And soundness/completeness of the proof procedure is exactly equivalent to correctness of the semidecision procedure.

(Of course we do have to keep separate, in either case, the *object* and the *verification*: an algorithm on its own isn't a proof of anything.)